# Plot Different Data Frame in Single Line Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have Different Data Frame with same length let's say 10 rows with different values. The First Data frame is Static, however rest of them are user input let's say user want 2 data frame then total it would be three data frame with same length. I would like to plot values for all three of them in one line graph in python.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L1 = pd.DataFrame([20,19,18,17,16,15])
K1 = pd.DataFrame([15,14,13,11,18,21])
k2 = pd.DataFrame([10,15,16,21,22,25])

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(L1[0])
ax1.plot(k1[0])
ax1.plot(k2[0])
fig1.savefig(Path + "abc.png")
```

I tried above but it just plot only L1 and K1 when I run it in a loop. How can I plot all three data frames in one figure?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `pandas.DataFrame`s when these look like they should just be lists or Numpy arrays?

Comment: Also, your capitalization is inconsistent, so the code you shared won't run as is.

Comment: You make reference to a loop, but I don't see any loop.

Comment: What loop? The code generates the plot you need with all 3 lines in one figure.

Comment: You can combine the dataframes and plot the one that has all of them. You won't need loops or extra hoops that way.

Comment: Do one of the solutions answer your question? If one does, you can click the gray check next to the solution to accept it. If not, please clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create a subplots set number of rows and columns `plt.sublots(nbrow, nbcol)`
this will return two objects: figure and axis of main frame each axis being a subplot

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


L1 = pd.DataFrame([20,19,18,17,16,15])
K1 = pd.DataFrame([15,14,13,11,18,21])
k2 = pd.DataFrame([10,15,16,21,22,25])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1)
axs[0].plot(L1.values)
axs[1].plot(K1.values)
axs[2].plot(k2.values)
axs[0].set_ylabel('YLabel 0')
axs[1].set_ylabel('YLabel 1')
axs[2].set_ylabel('YLabel 2')
fig.align_ylabels()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just have numbers, I don't see the reason to use a pandas `DataFrame`, so I converted them to numpy arrays. Then it's just a matter of plotting each of the arrays in a single subplot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

L1 = np.array([20,19,18,17,16,15])
K1 = np.array([15,14,13,11,18,21])
k2 = np.array([10,15,16,21,22,25])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(L1, label="L1")
ax.plot(K1, label="K1")
ax.plot(k2, label="k2")
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel("index")
```

[image]